# If two matrices A and B have the same determinant, are AB and BA similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If two matrices A and B have the same determinant, are AB and BA similar? How would I prove it?
I'm learning this topic for a data science course, and I don't have a mathematical background. We haven't covered eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials yet. It would be helpful if you can answer without using those concepts.
Thanks

Comment: no. but yes if the determinant is non-zero

Comment: $AB$ and $BA$ are always similar whenever at least one of them is invertible, with the invertible one serving as the similarity transform: $A^{-1}(AB)A = (A^{-1}A)BA = BA$, $B(AB)B^{-1} = BA (BB^{-1}) = BA$. The case where $A$ and $B$ are both singular is less clear.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. For example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
Note that $\det(A) = \det(B) = 0$. On the other hand, $AB \neq 0$ and $BA = 0$, but the only matrix similar to the zero matrix is the zero matrix itself.